# how can I config jetty version with maven-jetty-plugin?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I want to run a webapp with Jetty-6.1.25, but how can I config the version number of jetty with maven-jetty-plugin?

Answer (score 3):

add a <version>6.1.25</version> element as a sibling of the  to the maven-jetty-plugin...I have to note that we have released jetty 9 at this point though, with updated coordinates of org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin